# Add shadow to UILabel with rounded corners swift

Tags: swift, uilabel

i want to achieve something like this:
[image: Pic]

I have set rounded corners on my UILabel like this:

```
label.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
label.clipsToBounds = true
```

and I have tried adding a shadow like this:

```
func dropShadow(color: UIColor, opacity: Float = 0.5, offSet: CGSize, radius: CGFloat = 1, scale: Bool = true) {
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
    layer.shadowOffset = offSet
    layer.shadowRadius = radius

    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to achieve by adding a UILabel inside UIView

```
  viewlbl.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    viewlbl.clipsToBounds = true
    viewlbl.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    viewlbl.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    viewlbl.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
    viewlbl.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    viewlbl.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

[image]

Comment: This unfortunately applies the shadow to the text instead of the UILabel itself

Comment: @Lukas I edited my answer. Try that once again